# usages of participles, complement after linking verbs or adverb of cause?

Tags: participles

I wanna know the usage of participle below:

I simply feel better knowing a pen is handy.

Is the participle "knowing" here functioning as adverb of reason, namely, because he knows a pen is handy, he simply feel better?
Or is the participle functioning as complement after linking verb?

Comment: It can't be complement of "better" because gerund-participials don't function as complements to adjectives. It's an adjunct in clause structure, though I wouldn't call it a reason adjunct -- possibly a peripheral case of means. The predicative complement of "feel" is just "better".

Comment: Does an adjunct in clause structure function as an adverb?